# how to Highlight color on image for android Imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, highlight

I am working on imageview.i set image in imagesrc.but i want to highlight this image like below.

original Image:

[image]

I  need output as below Image:

[image]

give me some idea's so I can do that.

**Your answer would be appreciated.**

Comment: Can u please share original image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper solution is below:

```
greenCircle.getDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#70FFFF80"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `foreground` property and set alpha as per your requirement

```
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foreground="#70FFFF80"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image"/>
```

Comment: I have worked with this code. What issue are you facing with this?

Comment: i checked its not working.i want colors on images same like above.